# Using CSV file as datasource

Tags: csv, data-processor

I was trying to use the CSV file as a datasource but couldn't find documentation on how to form the URI. Having the CSV file hosted and using the URL https://... to refer to the csv doesn't work as the field names remain empty. Also, if I were to host the CSV file on the CIVICRM server itself, how should the URI be formed ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you are trying to do? I assume you are using the Data Processor extension? Do you want to import the file? Or just report on it?

Comment: Thanks Erik.  The way I understand CSV File as the data source in DataProcessor is that a CSV file can be use as a lookup table to be joined with the other data sources.  So specifically here i should be able to output the corresponding value in the CSV file given the joined field e.g 879 to "Alor Star".  The problem I have is how to get data processor to consume the CSV file properly as i have tried the HTTPS way and the full path specification of the URI  ( to the CIVICRM temp file upload folder on the same server) and there was no available fields in the CSV file shown.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert in the Data Processor but perhaps @Jaap Jansma can help you.....

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an url with https, http (e.g. `https://my.server.com/myfile.csv`) or use a local path (`/var/www/mycsv.csv`)

For urls your server needs to be able to open URLs with `fopen`.

The CSV data source uses the `fopen` function for reading the CSV file. More documentation on what kind of filenames can be used see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php